# Xcode project between 3.2 and 3.1

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I started an Xcode project in 3.1 using Leopard. Then I took this project home to work on it over the weekend.  At home, I have Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard.  Since then, I have switched many times between developing this project on Leopard/3.1 and Snow Leopard/3.2.  The project compiles fine on either setup.  But, if I build on 3.1 (in release mode), the executable will not run in Snow Leopard.  And If I build in 3.2, the executable will not run in Leopard.

My project settings are for 32-bit universal, base SDK 10.5, and the Release mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any answer, I just wanted to say I share your pain wrt Leopard/Snow Leopard incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from leopard to snow leopard and back isn't good, because snow leopard doesn't work well with leopard and vice versa.  To resolve this issue, upgrade both machines to snow leopard and the latest version of xcode.  But before you do that, try cleaning your project first then compile.

Comment: What if one of the computers is PowerPC-based then?

Comment: Then you have a problem, unfortunately.  You might be using a  statement that is only available in snow leopard, and isn't in leopard.

Comment: Alexy, let's assume I have both machines on Snow Leopard and I build the app on SL.  Then I still don't have a working version of the app for Leopard.  So how do you write Leopard programs using Xcode 3.2 in Snow Leopard?

Comment: It's difficult, from my experience.  I couldn't find a way how to do it.  If you build it on leopard, then there is a chance that it could work on snow leopard.

Comment: Alexy, thanks for your help.  Do you know why Apple still supports 10.5, but it wants its developers on 10.6 (which makes it difficult to develop for 10.5)?

Comment: It wants its developers to be on 10.6 because Apple wants people to use the latest version for developing apps.  People may be persuaded to upgrade their computer when they see "Mac OS 10.6 is required to open..."  Apple generally supports the latest OS, and then an OS before it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will answer my own question, or at least, try to explain it.

I was transferring the Xcode project files from Leopard to Snow Leopard via DropBox (this problem also happened via a USB flash drive transfer).

When I tried to open the target application after moving through DropBox, the app wouldn't open.  I opened the Console, and got a "posix_spawnp(blabla). Permission denied"  So, it's a permissions issue. (sudo chmod a+x /username/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName would let me run the app).

I dunno if I need to fix permissions on my Dropbox folder on my local machine, or if it's a problem with the DropBox service.

But to transfer the app from Leopard to Snow Leopard, first I must zip the app and transfer the zip file via DropBox.  Apparently, zipping preserves the permissions of the .app and doesn't let DropBox mess with it.